# Video html5 element doesn't work properly on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, html5-video

After doing a fresh Laravel install, I tried adding `<video src="/sample.mp4" width="800" height="400" controls></video>` element. The video and all controls shows up right, but if you try to skip to other time on the video it will either start again from the start or wouldn't skip at all.

This only happens when trying to use the `<video>` element on laravels blade. what might be the problem?

Comment: Skipping relies in large part on HTTP Range Requests. If those are not supported, then the browser would have to download the whole file sequentially, at least up to the point that you want to jump to. Does the video file get delivered directly via the web server in both cases here; or does putting this into a blade template perhaps somehow trigger that the file is served by Laravel/via PHP? The web server usually has range requests implemented by default, but any operation serving files via a script usually has to explicitly implement it.

Comment: The latter makes sense cause the skipping problem only happens if I am trying to include file locally from `/public` directory. But it works fine if I try to use external video link instead.